# Extracting data from Excel to R as it is

Tags: r

I have a excel containing values. The values are merged at some places like shown below (Table A). While extracting into R, I get in a different way like shown below (Table B)

Table A

[image]

```
library(readxl)
Book3 <- read_excel("~/Book3.xlsx")
```

Table B

[image]

If you look at table B, NA's are introduced in between where the values are merged. Is there a way to eliminate this. I need exactly the same in Excel. Please guide

Comment: How would you want to store this data in R? A data.frame just cannot have values span multiple columns. Everything must be rectangular: every rows has same number of columns.

Comment: I need to store this data in R as it is. For example, like Table A only. Is it not possible?

Comment: It is not possible. You could add another column labeled BC and move 5 and 6 to it after importing. What kind of analyses are you planning on the data?

Comment: There is a function called Kable in R. We can display the table very similar to Excel. Now what is happening is when I import file in R, NA's are introduced and I have to delete it every time and it is time consuming.

Comment: DevP, I don't think you're listening. R does not allow merged cells in `data.frame`-like objects. Since you are planning to use `knitr::kable`, then it needs to be `data.frame`-like, which means you are affected by the base constraint. You have two options: (1) make them the same value, or (2) make one of them `NA` or any empty string (so one might infer it's the same ... but it isn't really that great an option). Even the more-complex [`gt`](https://github.com/rstudio/gt) package doesn't merge cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `read.xlsx` function from openxlsx package. `fillMergedCells = T` can fill both the columns with the same values.

```
library(openxlsx)
read.xlsx(data, fillMergedCells=T)
```

If You are considering only the look and feel of the table as the same as in Excel than try flextables which can show exactly the same merged output as in Excel Like This Table below

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It is almost working. It is not exactly same. For example, 5 and 6 are also appearing in column C. Is there a way to tackle this?

Comment: As I said, If the main concern is the look of the table than you can try flextables